# Completing square quadric equation

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, quadrics

I am trying to find a canonical form for the quadric $x^2+y^2-3z^2-2xy-xz-6yz=0$ by completing squares.
For example, if it were $x^2+y^2-3z^2-2xy-6xz-6yz=0$, I would write
$$x^2+y^2-3z^2-2xy-6xz-6yz=(x-y-3z)^2-12(z+\frac12y)^2+3y^2=0$$ and letting $X:=x-y-3z, Z:=\sqrt{12}(z+\frac12y), Y:= \sqrt{3}y$. We get $Z^2=X^2+Y^2$ and so it is a cone.

I need to apply same method to above quadric but I could not.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this: $$x^2+y^2-3z^2-2xy-xz-6yz=(x-y+3z)^2-7xz-12z^2= \\(x+y-3z)^2-12(z+\frac{7}{24}x)^2+\frac{49}{48}x^2$$

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I’d like to ask one more if you wouldn’t mind. Shouldn’t we write $x^2+y^2-3z^2-2xy-xz-6yz=(x-y+3z)^2-7xz-12z^2= (x+y+3z)^2-12(z+\frac{7}{24}x)^2+\frac{49}{48}x^2$?

Comment: @user519955: You are right! I fixed it.

Comment: Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1):

If you really want the canonical form, caring about metric properties, [orthogonally diagonalize](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=orthogonally+diagonalize+matrix%28%5B1%2C-1%2C-1%2F2%5D%2C%5B-1%2C1%2C-3%5D%2C%5B-1%2F2%2C-3%2C-3%5D%29): Your equation is approximately

$$-4.75182(0.158224x+ 0.478112y+ 0.863929z)^2 + 2.846(0.348633x-0.845649y+ 0.404145z)^2+0.905819(-0.923807x -0.237249y + 0.300488z)^2=0.$$

In this case, however, applying the standard dehomogenization, and looking at the parabola you get, there is a standard focus/directix form, that appeals to me:

$$2\cdot((x+\frac{47}{56}z)^2+(y-\frac{23}{56}z)^2-(x+y+\frac{61}{28}z)^2/2)=0$$ or $$\frac{(56x+47z)^2+(56y-23z)^2-2\cdot (28x+28y+61z)^2}{2^57^2}=0.$$

You can of course apply any metric properties preserving map (mapping any plane to $z=1$), dehomogenize and write the resulting conic section in focus/directrix form (for ellipses and hyperbolae there are two), homogenize again, and use the inverse map to get as many representations you want, few of which are nice.